# How to analyse a core dump from a different machine?

Tags: linux

I'm new to analysing core dumps.
I find myself with the vmcore file from different machines but when trying to run the crash command it complains the system is running a different version of kernel.
How to analyse core dumps on a different server?
Thanks.

Comment: You can always create a VM with the same kernel/software installed.

Comment: Sometimes I have to do many upgrades until I have the exact same kernel version. This process takes a huge amount of time. I was wondering if I was missing something that others do to make the analysis of core dumps a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

Use the exact kernel version on the analysis host as the host that crashed.  `uname -r` should match.

[crash when used on a dump file](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/kernel_crash_dump_guide#sect-crash-running-the-utility) requires on the command line the (optionally compressed)  vmlinux binary probably somewhere under `/usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/`, then the vmcore file that is the dump.

Also for user programs, ensure the same packages are installed as the crashing system. Useful to debug program crashes with gdb, or for testing applications in general.

Apply the same patching procedure to this analysis system, or restore an OS backup if you have that.

Debuggers are loading symbols, function names and such, into memory dumps of what the system state was. The versions need to match precisely or this will not work.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I wish there was an easier way to analyse system issues though. I would gladly welcome any efforts to make these analysis easier.